# How to run 'import data'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to run the script below.

```
#------------Necessary Variables--------------#
import datetime as dt
symbols = ['INTC','VZ','AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MSFT', 'CAT', 'AXP', 'BA', 'GE', 'CVX', 'HD', 'NKE', 'PFE', 'MMM', 'TRV', 'UTX', 'MRK', 'DIS', 'DWDP', 'JNJ']
allocations = [25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25]
start_date = dt.date(2017, 1, 3)

#Benchmark Index
bench_symbol = "SPY"
#RF Syntax: 6 MO, 2 YR etc.
rate = '1 YR'
rf_start_date = dt.date(2017, 1, 3)

#For Quandl
api_key = "key_here"

#Dirctory Input For Data and Reports
root_path = "C:\\Users\\Excel\\Documents\\Python Scripts"
end_date = dt.date.today()

#------------Run Program----------------------#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #1.) Import the module
    import data

    #Select Functions
    data.portfolio()
    data.benchmark()
```

It almost seems like it is run from some kind of Console window.  I've never run any Python code that way before, and that doesn't seem right to me.

The code comes from the link below.

http://programmingforfinance.com/2018/02/tracking-a-portfolio-with-python/

Comment: Run the file from the command line, so open a console and type `python file_name.py`

Comment: to protect your account, remove your `api_key` from this post and put a "dummy" value

Comment: Chrisz, I tried the following: 'python __main__.py' in the Anacondo Colsole window.  I got this: 'python: can't open file '__main__.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'  What could be wrong here?

Comment: what did you name the script that you saved? `'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'` suggests your script is not named `main.py`, so whatever the script name, replace `main.py` with the name of your python script

Comment: I don't know what's going on here.  I know the path is correct; everything is spelled correctly.  There must be an easier way to run this script.  Normally I would hit F5, or select the code I want to run and hit F9.  Can't I just dispense with the Console window and run the script the usual way?

Comment: do you have a "old" program that you have run before named `main.py` somewhere? check your "run" settings (https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~feeg1001/labs/firststeps/index.html#id1) to see if you have a saved setting that gets run instead of the script in your editor.